# Count number of views

Tags: google-swiffy

I'm using google-swiffy and it's working. I can easily convert the flash files into HTML5. The problem is that I can't count the number of click of my banners access. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way to solve my problem.
I add this line of code
stage.setFlashVars("clickTAG=%%CLICK_URL_ESC%%http://websiteURL.com");

right above the line that cotains this: stage.start();

Doing this the DFP ins counting views and impressions and redirecting to the advertiser website.

Comment: Yes Ricardo. That's how you should do it. Any custom code (not limited to Swiffy) must contain %%CLICK_URL_ESC%%http://websiteURL.com in order track clicks accurately.